Batteries safe for use in low-pressure conditions
I want to create a device for use in skydiving.
Why when there are ready-made solutions? Because I am a skydiver and an electronics hobbyist, I would like to create something myself and experiment with different functions.
I need a way to power this device, but as this is quite a dangerous activity I need to choose the safest possible power source. The conditions I have to deal with are very low pressure with pressure drops from 1050hPa to ~600hPa, and temperature drops of 15-25 degrees in 15-30 minutes. I need a battery with a minimum capacity of 500mAh to be able to power the device for a reasonable time.
I was considering AA batteries or 18650 cells for an early prototype to simplify the construction of the device as much as possible (no integrated charger etc.), such batteries are also resistant to mechanical damage. However, I am puzzled by the resistance of such batteries to such large changes in pressure and temperature, I don't want the energy source to leak or even worse case the device to catch fire while the plane is climbing (once I've jumped out of the plane it's much easier to get rid of it).
Can you recommend energy sources that are most resistant to repeated rapid temperature and pressure changes of large magnitude.

Welcome! Some satellites have batteries and there are even battery driven turbopumps for the first stage in some smaller launch vehicles which will experience lower than sea level pressure. Have you found anything about such applications by searching? Space rated = expensive, but may point you in the right direction.

I'm not sure why you think those are large changes in temperature and pressure. They still fall within the normal operating range of most electronics, including batteries.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@RoyC  1.7 orders of magnitude, no?

@Sphero Pefhany you are quite correct I was confusing my pressure units. Venting starts around 20,000 hPa. Which is a lot bigger than the 400 hPa variation in the question.
